# Two-tailed p-value for Pearson's $r$

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance, p-value, python

The SciPy implementation of Pearson's $r$ [also gives a two-tailed $p$-value](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/stats/stats.py#L2420).

I understand that a $p$-value for a given correlation gives the probability of a correlation coefficient at least as big to be observed if the null hypothesis is true.

I find it hard to understand how this test can be two-tailed, however. What would be the meaning of a one-tailed $p$-value for non-correlation, then? Since $r$ is signed I think only a one-tailed p-value could satisfy the definition given above.

Comment: You may be able to answer the question yourself if you consider two of the possible null hypotheses that you might have when testing a correlation: 1) That r equals zero; 2) That r is not greater than 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so this is actually quite easy:

- A 2-tailed p-value gives the probability of a correlation at least as extreme as r to be observed if the true correlation is in fact zero.
- A 1-tailed p-value gives the probability of a correlation at least as extreme as r to be observed if the true correlation is in fact zero, or of the opposite sign than r.